# Change user role if checkout custom checkbox is checked in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-roles

I'm trying to add a custom function to my child-themes functions.php file where a checkbox is added to the bottom of the billing details form on the checkout page.

This checkbox asks the customer if they'd like to become a wholesale customer.

```
function customise_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option($checkout) {

echo '<div id="wholesale_checkbox_wrap">';
woocommerce_form_field('wholesale_checkbox', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'class' => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label' => __('Would you like to apply for a wholesale account?'),
    'placeholder' => __('wholesale'),
    'required' => false,
    'value'  => true
), $checkout->get_value('wholesale_checkbox'));
echo '</div>';

}
```

This works fine, however I'm having trouble with this next part..

I would like the customers user role to save as "wholesale_customer" instead of "customer" if they check the checkbox.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'customise_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option');

function wholesale_customer( $order_id ) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

if (isset($_POST['wholesale_checkbox'])) {

    if ($order->user_id > 0) {
        $user = new WP_User($order->user_id);
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role('customer');
        // Add role
        $user->add_role('wholesale_customer');
    }
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wholesale_customer' );
```

The above function works by saving the customer as a "wholesale_customer" when I remove the wholesale_checkbox if statement. But with the if statement included, it always saves the role as "customer".

Where am I going wrong? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option' );
function custom_checkout_field_with_wholesale_option( $checkout ) {

    if( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) ) return; // exit if it is "wholesale customer"

    echo '<div id="wholesale_checkbox_wrap">';
    woocommerce_form_field('wholesale_checkbox', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label' => __('Would you like to apply for a wholesale account?'),
        'placeholder' => __('wholesale'),
        'required' => false,
        'value'  => true
    ), '');
    echo '</div>';

}

// Conditionally change customer user role
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wholesale_option_update_user_meta' );
function wholesale_option_update_user_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['wholesale_checkbox']) ) {
        $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true ); // Get user ID
        if( $user_id > 0 ){
            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->remove_role('customer');
            $user->add_role('wholesale_customer');
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks heaps work a charm first try. Hopefully other people will find this as helpful as I have.

Comment: One more question @LoicTheAztec - How can I add the same checkbox with the same function to the account registration page?

Comment: @jvandelaar May be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170304/populating-woocommerce-custom-fields/49173586#49173586) will show you the way

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec that has helped with the next part of the project I was working on. However still can't get the same checkbox working. It seems that the line ", $checkout->get_value('wholesale_checkbox')" breaks the rest of the form underneath. Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: @jvandelaar I have updated my answer as `$checkout->get_value('wholesale_checkbox')` is not really needed in this case and can be replaced with `''`